# Anyone interested in collaborate to build a "How to ask a question about [google-sheets]" guide/faq?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

In 2020 when this question was originally posted and still at the end of February, 2023, [google-sheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-sheets) is the tag with the higher number of questions in Web Applications SE.  Unfortunately people answering questions are, IMHO, very few, and voting are also very few.

Besides of the different reasons that we could discuss, I believe that **recent quality questions** help to keep knowledgeable people interested. I also belive that "broken windows" might cause people ask questions that doesn't belogs to this site, have wrong expectations and derive in unnesary conflicts.

NOTE: "broken window" is a term taken from the "real world" to apply to Stack Exchange posts that are used as excuse to allow deviation from the aspirations and workings of the corresponding community. Meta Stack Exchange has a tag about this -> [[broken-windows]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/broken-windows/info).

Many askers someway found this site and post their question without having any badge or reputation. Per se that isn't bad but usually those questions:

1. Need more details
2. Need more focus
3. Ask to find a feature, formula, script, add-on or reference

From time to time we also found questions about Google Sheets that asks about how to develop a web application

Some of these questions include a link to a spreadsheet but it doesn't really help to understand the question. It's worthy to mention that not all of these users as aware that sharing an spreadsheet reveal their Google Account name and that could also reveal their email address.

I'm wandering if there are people here interested in collaborate to create an extended version of "How to ask good question?" pointed to people asking questions using the [google-sheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-sheets) or in improving the corresponding tag wiki.

The following search, in February 24th 2023, [[google-sheets] created:30d.. isanswered:0 answers:1 hasaccepted:0](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-sheets%5D+created%3A30d..+isanswered%3A0+answers%3A1+hasaccepted%3A0) returned 28 questions with score = 0 having at least one answer, considered not answered because the answers haven't a positive score.

---

Stats of the last 30 days taken in February 24, 2023.

[image: Stats for [google-sheets], February 24, 2023]

[image: Top Answerers in the last 30 for [google-sheets]]

---

Related

- [Why aren't people voting? How can we get people to get more engaged?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2701/88163)
- [How do we promote knowledgeable people to answer questions here on Web Applications](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2491/88163)
- [Do we need to extend the [importxml] wiki?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4533/88163)
- [Please remind people that questions and answers must contain the data](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4673/88163)
- [Feedback to 'please write a script for me' questions?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4697/88163)

---

### Recent related posts

#### From Meta Web Applications SE

- [Let's make "research efforts" more specific: request to search the web app help](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4893/88163)

#### From Super User

- [How to fix an unfocused post, that I thought was pretty well focused](https://meta.superuser.com/q/14912/152004) (I posted an answer with stuff that might be included here)

---

From [How to ask a good question?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

> ## How to ask a good question?
>
> We’d love to help you. To **improve your chances** of getting an answer,
> here are some tips:
>
> ### [Search](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/search), and research
>
> Have you [**thoroughly searched for an answer**](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/search) *before* asking your
> question? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found
> and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken
> the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious
> answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant
> answer!
>
> ### Be on-topic
>
> Our community is defined by a specific set of topics that you
> [can view in the help center](http://developers.google.com/apps-script); please stick to those topics and
> [avoid asking for opinions or open-ended discussion](http://www.google.com/google-d-s/accessibility/spreadsheets.html). If your question is about the site
> itself, ask on our meta-discussion site. If you’re looking for a
> different topic, it might be covered on another [Stack Exchange site](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Docs,_Sheets,_and_Slides).
>
> ### Be specific
>
> If you ask a vague question, you’ll get a vague answer. But if you
> give us details and context, we can provide a useful answer.
>
> ### Make it relevant to others
>
> We like to help as many people at a time as we can. Make it clear how
> your question is relevant to more people than just you, and more of us
> will be interested in your question and willing to look into it.
>
> ### Keep an open mind
>
> The answer to your question may not always be the one you wanted, but
> that doesn’t mean it is wrong. A conclusive answer isn’t always
> possible. When in doubt, ask people to cite their sources, or to
> explain how/where they learned something. Even if we don’t agree with
> you, or tell you exactly what you wanted to hear, remember: we’re just
> trying to help.

---

## Tag wiki

> ## Overview
>
> One of the applications of the Google Docs editors to create and work on Google's own spreadsheet format. It can be accessed from
> Google Drive or from http://sheets.google.com.
>
> NOTE: On the official documentation "spreadsheet" is used instead of
> "workbook" and "sheet" instead of "worksheet". The app's name has
> changed and was previously Google Spreadsheets.
>
> Within the spreadsheet, all basic functions ([see complete list](https://support.google.com/drive/bin/static.py?topic=25273&page=table.cs&ctx=tooltip))
> and more are present to accomplish many goals. Do not expect Sheets to
> mimic Excel exactly. For user-specific features, [Google Apps
> Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/) can create custom functions and allows for extra
> flexibility inside and outside the spreadsheet.
>
> ## General asking guidance Before posting a question:
>
> - Check the [Official Documentation](http://support.google.com/docs) and make use of Sheet's inbuilt Help, in particular for the syntax
>   required by
>   [functions](https://support.google.com/docs/table/25273?visit_id=1-636459177854577018-232500333&hl=en&rd=2).
> - Search for related questions & answers tagged [google-sheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-sheets).
> - If you get "#ERROR! > Error: Parse error on formula", check that your formula is using the correct argument separator. Some locales use
>   a comma, others a semicolon (set at sheet level).
> - Mention if you are using a version other than English.
> - If your question is about a complex formula that is not working, (1) check that each part works correctly and (2) mention which specific
>   part is not working and (3) in what way/where it fails.
> - Be certain to provide cell references where relevant (eg avoid cropping the Headings [A, B, C etc across the top, 1, 2, 3 etc. down
>   the side] when uploading an image).
> - Where values that are expected to be the same are not, check for surplus spaces (especially trailing ones).
> - Share a link to a testsheet, following the guidelines here: [How to share a Google Sheets demo spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/138382/136642)
>
> **Do's**   The tag can be used by itself or in combination with other tags:
>
> - [google-sheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-sheets)[google-form](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-form) or [google-sheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-sheets)[google-apps-script](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script)
> - [google-sheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-sheets)[google-drive](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-drive)<sup>†</sup>[pdf](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pdf)
>
> (<sup>†</sup> to indicate that you want to convert the spreadsheet to
> PDF in Google Drive.)
>
> Others tags that may be relevant include:
>
> [google-sheets-addons](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-sheets-addons) [google-sheets-charts](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-sheets-charts)
> [google-sheets-performance](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-sheets-performance) [google-sheets-query](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-sheets-query)
> [google-sheets-timestamp](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-sheets-timestamp)
>
> If the question is about a formula:
>
> - Include the formula
> - Include a **representative sample** of the source data, preferably in **text** format
> - Include **exactly** what results are required from the source data, and where
> - Include, where appropriate, a link to a demo spreadsheet shared with anyone with the link is able **to view** but do **not** rely on the
>   sheet or images to clarify what should be stated in words
>
> **Dont's**   Without good reason, do not use the [google-drive](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-drive) tag in combination with the [google-sheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-sheets) tag, to point to the
> Google Sheets. This will make both tags contaminated.
>
> ## Automating tasks / add custom functions and features
>
> We can use macros to record recurring steps as far as the procedure is
> simple. For complex automation, adding custom functions and features
> we could use [Google Apps Script](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Before asking a question that
> involves macros and scripts, please read [Extending Google
> Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets).
>
> ## How to get more specific guidance on asking questions about Google Sheets
>
> Request for help about how to ask a question on [Meta Web
> Applications](http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/).
>
> ## References
>
> - [Google fact sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)
> - [Google Docs, Sheets, and Slides Wikipedia](http://stackexchange.com/sites)

Comment: What are your thoughts on a separate SE site for office applications: be it MS, Google, Libreoffice, Open office, and the others out there?

Comment: @SeverusSnape Is there already a community about that somewhere ?

Comment: No Sir. There isn't one. I was wondering if proposing one in [area51.se] could be good. I am a great fan of libreoffice, and the only place it fits in SO as of now. Maybe having a different SE site for office suites would be better.

Comment: @SeverusSnape Before proposing a site on Area 51 there should be a community interested on such site otherwise it is very likely that the proposal be closed.

Comment: @SeverusSnape https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/libreoffice